# query error and result bad value for type int : 8962101012749336481

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

hello I'm trying to make a rest API, by querying "where" based on date. I connect with postgresql.

I have an entity like this

> @Entity
>   @Table(name ="device")
>   public class DeviceEntity {

```
@Column(name="updated")
private Date updated;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "phone")
private String phone;

@Column(name = "accountid")
private String accountid;

@Column(name = "accountname")
private String accountname;
```

and this is my query:

> @Repository
>   public interface DeviceRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository {

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM device_data WHERE updated = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
Page<DeviceEntity> findByUserAndStatusOrderByCreatedAtDesc(Date updated, PageRequest pageRequest
        );}
```

after running and test url, i'm getting error "bad value for type int : 8962101012749336481"

Answer (score 0):

`8962101012749336481` This is already beyond INT datatype

you should be using `BIGINT`

See [DBFIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=0Sa0p6cqT7)

Various INT datatype in postgresql can be found [here](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-integer/)